# when to use singleton objects and when to use actual objects in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, singleton

I would like to know if there is any specific rule or if there is a rule of thumb to be followed on using actual objects in scala vs singleton objects in scala

say i have a class like this

```
class GetDataInput {
 def getNameInput() {
 println("Enter the name value: ")
}
 def getTypeInput() {
   println("Enter the type value: ")
  }
 def getBothInput() {
   println("Enter the name value: ")
  println("Enter the type value: ")
 }
}
```

is it better to use it in regular terms like

```
val someval = new GetDataInput()
someval.getNameInput()
```

or is it good to create a singleton object for this class and access the methods using that

```
object GetDataInput {
  def getNameInp() = getNameInput()
}
```

Any pointers on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you make an `object` when:

- It makes absolutely no sense of having different instances of a potential class, for example, to enclose several pure functions (like methematical functions, factory methods)
- You want to write the equivalent of java `static` method or `static final` constants. (see Companion objects).
- You want a simpler alternative for enum values (a `sealed trait` extended by `object`instances).

In your example, all the functions are pure, and the class is stateless. Therefore all instances will be strictly equal. It makes sense to turn it into an object:

```
object GetDataInput {
  def getNameInput() {
    println("Enter the name value: ")
  }
  ...
}
```

If you made the wrong choice, don't worry, it is easy to refactor. Usually you can keep all existing calls to the object, simply by extracting the methods in a trait:

```
trait GetDataInput {
   def getNameInput() {
    println("Enter the name value: ")
  }
}

object GetDataInput extends GetDataInput //Bring all traits methods into the object
                                         // to keep previous behaviour

class MyGetDataInput( whatever: Foo ) extends GetDataInput {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The question is rather: "Do you need different instances of a type?" If so, then go for a class (or a trait), if not go for a singleton. And btw there are no specific guidelines for the language you are using only because it has the singleton pattern built into it.

Answer (score 2):

In scala, one primary use of objects is to fill the role of singletons.  If you want to use a class as a singleton, just declare the class itself as an object.  Then you could do:

```
GetDataInput.getNameInput()
```

Internally, scala will lazily create a single instance of your class and keep it alive for the duration of the program, so anytime you call a method on the object, you're really calling methods of a singleton instance of the class managed by the scala runtime.